# Cannot update UI using the UI thread Dispatcher?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, backgroundworker, dispatcher

I designed a WPF application based on MVVM pattern and I need to get large amount of data from a webservice, and i do it with a BackgroundWorker inside the ViewModel. To modify the observable collection i have to use a dispatcher and the problem is here, even if i pass by reference UI Dispatcher it dosen't work, it is like I use the inner dispatcher and my application get freezed until all data are retrived.

I try to get the UI Dispatcher in several ways, Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher, Application.Dispatcher, App.Current.Dispatcher... doing some researches I read that it should be works, does someone have any suggestions?

Thank you
Marco

**Update**

Here some code: This is how I pass the Dispatcher to the ModelView

```
void AppWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     this.DataContext = new ModelViewApplication(System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);
}
```

Then I try to get data in this way

```
public ModelViewApplication(Dispatcher _dispatcher)
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(getData);
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(completedData);

    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

public void getData(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    _dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new Action(
            delegate()
                 {
                 //Connect to webservice and retrieve data
                 ....
                 }));
}
```

It seems like the multithread dosen't work

Comment: If your application gets frozen then it looks like an issue with `BackgroundWorker`, not `Dispatcher`. Show us the code.

Comment: BackgroundWorker works fine because if I use just that not calling webservice I don't have any problems, but if I try to connect to webservice inside the DoWork event I get the error "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"

Comment: @Marco: The problem is not that the dispatcher is broken - but your use of it may be incorrect.  Post some code.

Comment: You have a bug in your code.  There is no way to tell from your question where or what it is.  You already know enough to fix your problem.  Here's a protip:  Create a new project which does one thing and one thing only--update the UI from a BackgroundWorker.  Isolate your issue in as little code as possible.  Either one of two things will happen:  One, you will figure out what you are doing wrong, and you will fix your own issue.  Two, you will have the same problem, but in such a small amount of code you can paste it in a question and let us all see what you're doing.

Comment: I posted some code, hope this helps

Comment: @Marco: It does, it does.  I think your problem is that you are unintentionally creating a closure that includes some UI or DependencyObject, so that within your `//connect to webservice` method you are accessing that object from the worker thread.

Comment: @Rachel I may should not use it with this implementation but that dosen't explain why it does not work, @ Will, I don't understand what do you mean, i just connet to my webservice end get data in an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `BackgroundWorker` to get your data, then use the `RunWorkerCompleted` to update the `ObservableCollection`. You shouldn't need the `Dispatcher` at all

```
public ModelViewApplication()
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(getData);
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += completedData;

    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

public void getData(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //Connect to webservice and retrieve data
    e.Result = WebService.GetData();
}

private void completedData(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<SomeClass>((IList)e.Results);
}
```

Comment: But what If i want to do some more complex things in the background thread updating the collection?

Comment: @Marco Like what? Depending on what you want to do, some of it can be done in the `BackgroundWorker`, others can be done through the `Dispatcher` (just don't run the dispatcher call from the background thread), and some can be done on the UI thread. It all depends on what you're doing.

Comment: So are you telling me there is no way to use Dispatcher inside a background thread?? is it right?

Comment: @Marco You can use the Dispatcher inside the BackgroundWorker, but why would you? Both run asynchronous to the UI thread so I don't really see a reason to run one inside another. I do know that long running processes on the Dispatcher CAN tie up the UI thread even if they are run at `DispatcherPriority.Background`. Because of that, I'd run certain processes on a `BackgroundWorker`, while other processes would get run on the `Dispatcher`

Comment: Ok I still don't understand why it doesn't work my code but I got your point, thank you for your help!!

Comment: @Marco I'd need to see what you have in `//Connect to webservice and retrieve data` to know why it doesn't work, but I am guessing you are accessing something there that can only be accessed from the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample which may help you implementing the task and UI Updates. You can easily convert the following sample to you scenario.
You can have a look at my blog which has detailed Explanation regarding this error and solution

http://bathinenivenkatesh.blogspot.com/2011/07/wpf-build-more-responsive-ui.html

```
ObservableCollection images = new ObservableCollection(); 
TaskFactory tFactory = new TaskFactory(); 
tFactory.StartNew(() => 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
    { 
        //GET IMAGE Path FROM SERVER 
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate() 
        { 
            // UPDATE PROGRESS BAR IN UI 
        }); 

        images.Add((""); 
    } 

}).ContinueWith(t => 
{ 
    if (t.IsFaulted) 
    { 
        // EXCEPTION IF THREAD IS FAULT 
        throw t.Exception; 
    } 
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate() 
    { 
        //PROCESS IMAGES AND DISPLAY 
    }); 
});
```